# how to render the content of the sidenavigation without affecting the mat-sidenav-content?

Tags: angular

I am having following code :

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
    <mat-sidenav #leftSidenav mode="push" opened>
      <app-left-menu></app-left-menu>
    </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>

    <main>
      <router-outlet>
      </router-outlet>
    </main>

  </mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
```

My issue is that the content of the sidenav-content is being covered/shadowed  when the sidenav bar is being toggled.
HOw can i make sure that the sidenav-content remains unaffected from the toggling of the sidebar?

Here  is the CSS code:

```
.main_content {
  width:96%; 
  height: calc(100vh - 100px); 
  background: #efefef;
  padding: 20px;
}
.sidenavContent{
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a CSS issue. Can you provide at the very least your CSS, and ideally a live demo.

Comment: The css files .main_content {
  width:96%; 
  height: calc(100vh - 100px); 
  background: #efefef;
  padding: 20px;
}
.sidenavContent{
  overflow:hidden;
}

Comment: This would be more helpful in the question so that everyone can see